# Where does 2^32 come from with bitcoin?

Tags: algorithms, hash, cryptography, hashing

Several months ago I was doing research into calculating mining revenue for several crypto currencies. When trying to calculate BTC revenue I found this value 1/2^32 which was described somewhere along the lines of the probability of finding or solving a block. This value worked for finding revenue for several coins including BTC, I assumed this meant they were on the same blockchain, but is that assumption correct? There was also ETH which didn't need a value like this because I think its probability value was very close to 1 so it didn't matter. This ETH version worked for several coins as well, but both equations couldn't be used for one coin. Which further cemented my assumption that it had to do with what blockchain/algorithm the coin was using.

The way I checked my work was by comparing my answer to several online calculators.

But how are these values found and how can I find them for alt coins that aren't as published? I can always use an online calculator for them but I would prefer to be able to find these values and do the revenue calculations long hand. An example of a coin I got stuck on was Flux neither the equation with the 2^32 or the equation for ETH worked for it. I tried solving for that "probability" variable. But the only way I think I could 100% match to what the online calculators  revenue was is to have an infinite system of equations that all solve for that value.

Comment: Can you show where you saw it? And, is this really a CS question or a Bitcoin question?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't realize how this website worked with different communities, not sure how the bitcoin community is though. Here is where I found it https://minerdaily.com/2021/how-are-bitcoins-difficulty-and-hash-rate-calculated/#:~:text=In%20this%20equation%20the%20probability,10%20minute)%20target%20block%20pace.

Comment: It's just part of the definition of difficulty. Difficulty is how many hashes you need to find a block (on average) divided by 2^32

Comment: @user253751 well no actually, that value is different for different coins.

Comment: there is a bitcoin stack exchange site